# Почему ошибка Callback в C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, callback

Ошибка при выполнении данного кода, выводит на linux

```
Test begin...
TestFunction, i = 0!!!
```

Код:

```
using System;

namespace Callback
{
    public class TestCallbacks
    {
        public Action<int, bool, decimal, decimal, bool> TestCallback;
    }

    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static TestCallbacks Callbacks;

        public static void Initialize(TestCallbacks callbacks)
        {
            Callbacks = callbacks;
        }

        public static void TestCallback()
        {
            // Passing i = 100!
            Callbacks.TestCallback(100, true, 200m, 300m, false);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static void TestFunction(int i, bool b1, decimal d1, decimal d2, bool b2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"TestFunction, i = {i}!!!");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test begin...");

            var testCallbacks = new TestCallbacks()
            {
                TestCallback = TestFunction
            };

            TestClass.Initialize(testCallbacks);

            TestClass.TestCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Каким компилятором (Mono, .NET Core) и какой версии пользуетесь?

Comment: @PetSerAl использую .NET Core 2.0

Comment: Можете указать полную версию (желательно версию SDK)? Их [тут](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0) больше чем одна. Также на этой странице указано *"This release has reached end of life, meaning it is no longer supported. We recommend moving to a supported release."* возможно следует обновится до более свежей версии.

Comment: @PetSerAl dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  cdcd1928c9

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     centos
 OS Version:  7
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         centos.7-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0

Comment: По всей видимости какая-то ошибка в среде выполнения 2.0.0 для Linux. Если запустить результат сборки в свежей версии .NET Core (2.2.1), то программа выдаёт верный результат: `i = 100`.

Answer (score 0):

Это не так. Скопировал твой код на ideone без изменений: https://ideone.com/j2FlsU.

Вот вывод:

```
Test begin...
TestFunction, i = 100!!!
```

И, естественно, там linux.

Comment: https://tio.run/##jZNRS8MwEMff@ymuw4cWalfnY50ggiAoDBR8EB/SLJbDNBlJOtHRz17TznXJtop5KEf7v/v9c3el@pxKxdq21ihKePrShlV5EAhSMb0ilMEt4bwg9CPYBGDPqi44UqCcaA3PTJvdd91/3ooc4Q01KMUVCpNAISVPYMkoVsQNuvfXXrG8L9MELlIbYnxyF52m/mo9f8NNdB6M6NcSl3Av0CDh@M0iP5/uonhI34O7s5fO9@J8kDR/Yl1WNEaYTmFhL92NCi3kIsvC0w5Sr5zVJWBUzRKYZVmVwGX/fCdcs9g16Njc9nmhZKlIddhlhWti2JH/u1r0447suAG3g4XiYhg1LN14thPMRhsqhZacpS8KDXtAwaKzictJ@i5ssAnDcBKf7LRr8ZGgiLRRtn2vb0BUqf8P7rlQsBJFmqYdzEtYEwXG25Y5CPbpb6Az1mNkd1y1LeBe1dM2B/Thb0id5fXsxKMZ/t4dL0PTtj8

Comment: @PetSerAl, хм.. Метки [tag:.net-core] у вопроса нет, но вообще да, внезапно... Как так?

Comment: Возможно бага в старой версии компилятора, учитывая что tio.run использует 2.3.2.61921. У меня на компьютере (не Linux) оба компилятора C# (Visual Studio 2017 и .NET Core) имеют версию 2.10.0.0 и выдают ожидаемый результат (`i = 100`).